# Running VM image created by Workstation in Windows in a Linux machine

Tags: linux, windows, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

I have a Windows machine, on which I'm running a VM image using Workstation. I would like to run this VM image on a Linux machine.

I know I at least need the Linux version of Workstation. But is the VM image OS-independent, i.e. I can just run it in the Linux machine, or do I need the VM image to have been created by a Linux Workstation in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

Practically, the whole point of desktop virtualization is being able to do that.

So, yes, it should work fine, especially if its both on VMware workstation. The hardware the VM sees would be identical.